# WP7 SQL Server CE query optimization

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce

EDIT: I have read a bit more on the topic and have realized that, [contrary to what is suggested](http://vantsuyoshi.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/how-to-prepopulate-wp7-local-database/), I just include the same .sdf file I generate for the desktop application with the mobile one. Since it seems that index formats are different between desktop/mobile (I have read warnings about the first database connection taking much longer as indices are rebuilt if this is done [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2009/04/01/after-moving-the-database-from-one-platform-to-other-the-first-sqlceconnection-open-takes-more-time.aspx)) and I am opening the database as read only from the installation folder, could it be that the engine is ignoring my indices entirely as it can't convert them?

I have a SQL Server CE 3.5 database with a single table, `Entities`, with about 146,000 rows and these columns: `Id (int, primary key), Gloss (nvarchar(4000)), GlossLen (int), Meaning (nvarchar(4000)`, and indices on `Gloss` and `Glosslen`. This is used by a cross platform application I am developing for Windows (WPF) and WP7.5.

I then run the following query against the database using LINQ to SQL:

```
(from d in Entities 
 where d.Gloss.StartsWith("searchstring") 
 orderby d.GlossLen ascending 
 select new 
        { Id = d.Id, WrittenForms = d.Gloss, MeaningsString = d.Meaning, 
          MatchString = d.Gloss, MatchStringLen = d.GlossLen }).Take(200)
```

The problem is am facing is that, while the query executes at reasonable speed (2 seconds or less) in Windows, it becomes painfully slow (6+ seconds) on on an actual WP7 device (the emulator is almost as fast as WPF).

As far as I can see, the generated SQL seems reasonable: below is what LINQPad returns.

```
SELECT TOP (200) 
    [t0].[Id], [t0].[Gloss] AS [WrittenForms], [t0].[Meaning] AS [MeaningsString], 
    [t0].[GlossLen] AS [MatchStringLen]
FROM [Entities] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Gloss] LIKE @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[GlossLen]
```

The query's execution plan as reported by Visual Studio is: Index Seek->Filter->Sort->Select, so I am not doing a table scan.

I have also already tried using `CompiledQuery.Compile` on the LINQ query, storing the generated Func for re-use, but have seen no improvement.

What am I doing wrong? The only difference between the WP7 and WPF code paths is that the WP7 database is opened from the installation folder as read only.

Comment: No,if the indexes required rebuild, you would get an error. The index issue relates to Windows Mobile, not Phone

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, but WP7 != Windows. I had similar issue, caused by the index being too wide, I created a column with only the first 12 charatcters, and indexed and searched that.

Comment: Ouch.  No idea why the Phone doesn't give access to the SQLCE engine directly, as this query could be improved an order of magnitude by avoiding the query processor and going table direct.

Comment: What is a good size for the indexed text columns then? Can I get away with, say, an nvarchar(100) or is that going to be too big as well?

Comment: Test, test, test.... Ctake: For INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs, the query processor is bypassed, if you use a rowversion column - see my blog

Comment: OK, I tried rebuilding the databases with Gloss set to nvarchar(32), which resulted in a much smaller index, but query execution speed didn't improve. Is there really a way of getting decent performance out of WP7 for this workload or am I asking too much of the Phone?

Comment: Try without the order by clause

Comment: Tried removing the order by clauses, query execution time is unchanged.

Comment: Do you need to display 200 records at one time?